# Why does running Update-Database on my empty production database not create any tables?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6, ef-code-first, entity-framework-migrations

I'm using Entity Framework code-first migrations.

During development, I created the database on the development database server, enabled code-first migrations, added an initial migration, ran `Update-Database`, made some changes to the models, added another migration, ran `Update-Database` again, etc. Everything works fine.

However, now that I'm ready to have it create the tables on the production database server, it doesn't work.

Here is what I did:

1. Changed the connection string in the `web.config` file to point to the production database server
2. Opened the Package Manager Console
3. Ran `Update-Database`

There is no error message. It just says

> No pending explicit migrations
> Running seed method

I'm using:

- `MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion`
- `AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = false`
- `AutomaticMigrationDataLossAllowed = false`
- Entity Framework 6

Am I misunderstanding how migrations are supposed to work? Do I need to do something more than change the connection string to point to the production server and run `Update-Database`?

Update: I'm an idiot. See my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good grief, I'm an idiot. I finally figured out the source of the problem.

While I had changed the connection string in `web.config` to that of the production database, I had done so **in the wrong project!** My solution contains both a "Web" project (which is where the Update-Database command was looking) and a "WebAPI" project (which is the one I was editing).

*sigh*